# MSVC name mangling

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker, name-mangling

I am trying to build Lua and QtLua with MSVC 2015 x86 and I have encountered an issue with exported/imported symbols.

Here is what I do forbuilding Lua 5.3.2 ([source](http://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/01/16/how-to-compile-lua-5-3-0-for-windows/)):

```
cl /MD /O2 /c /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL *.c
ren lua.obj lua.o
ren luac.obj luac.o
link /DLL /IMPLIB:lua5.3.2.lib /OUT:lua5.3.2.dll *.obj 
link /OUT:lua.exe lua.o lua5.3.2.lib 
lib /OUT:lua5.3.2-static.lib *.obj
link /OUT:luac.exe luac.o lua5.3.2-static.lib
```

So far it works and dependancy walker shows that functions are exported without any mangling.

Then I build QtLua using cmake and I'v got about 100 errors like:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_close referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall QtLua::State::~State(void)" (??1State@QtLua@@UAE@XZ)
```

So basically my issue is that the DLL exports `lua_close` and the linker looks for `_lua_close`.

After a bit of searching the `_lua_close` format seems legit as Microsoft documentation states that C symbols called with `__cdecl` are mangled with a '_' prefix.

However I don't get why the DLL exports unmangled names.

Function declaration when compiled in Lua (C files)

```
__declspec(dllexport) void (lua_close) (lua_State *L);
```

Function declaration when compiled in QtLua (C++ files)

```
extern "C" {
  extern void (lua_close) (lua_State *L);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick answer

MSVC did not found the lua DLL (or lib).

### Long answer

Exported C functions called using `__cdecl` are not mangled, whereas internal C functions called using `__cdecl` are mangled with a '_' prefix.

*Source: http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm*

To fix my issue I took all source files from QtLua and created a qmake project from them. And tadaa! It works! (Well, it doesn't because QtLua doesn't seem to be tested on anything else than gcc, but I got rid of this linker problem).

My conclusion is that:

- MSVC complains about not finding `_function` and is in fact looking for `function` (or maybe both).
- CMake, even if it found the lua library at config time, failed to pass the proper options to the linker at build time.